# How can I speed up this SQL update query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization, rows

The A table is huge (50+ millions rows) table. So this update method is too slow for MSSQL server. In addition to it runs in a store procedure's while loop. I think this solution is not quite effective.
Has Somebody any good idea to solve this problem?
Thanks!

**A table's definition**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [E_NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [h_out] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TAG] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [TAG1] [smallint] NOT NULL,

 CONSTRAINT [PK_A] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [E_NUM] ASC,
    [ID] ASC,
    [NUM] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**B table's definition**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NUM2] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TYPE] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [R_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_B] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [NUM] ASC,
    [NUM2] ASC,
    [TYPE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**UPDATE**

```
 UPDATE A_1 
 SET A_1.TAG1 = -1
 FROM A
 INNER JOIN B ON A.NUM = B.NUM
 INNER JOIN A AS A_1 ON B.NUM2 = A_1.NUM 
 WHERE A.TAG1 = -1 AND A.TAG = -1 AND B.TYPE='X'
 AND  A.E_num = A_1.E_num AND A.ID=A_1.[ID];
```

Comment: Index and query tuning is the first step to improve performance. Upload the actual execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the link to your question if you need help with that.

Comment: BTW, `A.TAG1 = -1 AND A.TAG = -1` is redundant but probably not related to the performance issue unless your intent is `B.TAG = -1`.

Comment: Why is it redundant? They are different columns.

Comment: The B.NUM, B.NUM2, B.TYPE had already had index. 
Thanks for your advices!

Comment: What about the columns in the WHERE clause? Are they indexed too?

Comment: The "A" table has no indices. i think it would slow the update down. (update recreates indices too)

Comment: What are the definitions of table A and B? What are the primary keys if any?

Comment: Can you add the DDL for the tables in your question please?

Comment: I added table definitions.

Comment: I think `WHERE A.TAG1 = -1` is redundant because you are setting `A_1.TAG1 = -1` to rows that already have this value. If  `A_1` and `A` are the same table, then I'd assume they are also the same row, since you have the condition `A.ID=A_1.[ID]`. Unless `ID` is not unique, of course.

Comment: Indexes will not always slow UPDATE if you are joining multiple tables in your UPDATE statement. The joins in UPDATE statement will slow down the joining part of your query and if you speed this up by adding appropriate indexes then the performance gain in joining might be better than slowdown due to index population, that will result in an overall performance improvement. So, try to optimize the join part using indexes.

Answer (score 0):

The Primary Keys(PKs are clustered by default) in MS SQL Server have very high performance(in compared with Oracle). So using correct PK and avoid updating them is important.

When joining tables it is better to target one table and narrow it by where clause and then use PK to reach records in the other tables. You can find out which table selected(targeted) by MS SQL Server by using execution plan.

I think you must declare a combined index on TAG and TAG1 columns in table A to target the table A. If `A.TAG1 = -1 AND A.TAG = -1` criteria narrow down table A correctly for example lower than 10000 rows have this value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I didn't make any mistakes, this should be equivalent to your UPDATE statement:

```
 UPDATE upd 
    SET upd.TAG1 = -1
   FROM A upd

   JOIN A 
     ON A.ID    = upd.ID
    AND A.E_NUM = upd.E_NUM
    AND A.TAG1 = -1 
    AND A.TAG  = -1 

   JOIN B 
     ON B.NUM  = A.NUM
    AND B.NUM2 = upd.NUM
    AND B.TYPE = 'X'
```

Since you don't have any indexes for things like `B.TYPE` or `A.TAG` etc.. the system is pretty much obliged to go over the entire table to find the applicable records. If your table is HUGE, then yes, this will takes some time.

Add these indexes and then try again:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1_A ON A (TAG, TAG1, ID, E_NUM) INCLUDE (NUM) -- NUM is implicit due to PK if you think about it
CREATE INDEX idx1_B ON B (TYPE, NUM, NUM2)
```

You're right to assume that updating `TAG1` will require updating `idx1_A` too, but this will still be a lot faster than scanning the entire table. (**)

You might want to add

```
  WHERE upd.TAG1 <> -1
```

to avoid having to update when the right value is already present to minimize the impact.

(**: if your update affects 80% of the records it might not be worth having the index on table A, but keep in mind that it would be a gigantic operation and as such will need a lot of time simply because it's a lot of work!)